# Wagtail. ValueError: Cannot create form field for 'site' yet, because its related model 'wagtailcore.Site' has not been loaded yet

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have wagtail project with two apps.
Doing makemigrations raise an error:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/oleh/Documents/us_website/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/oleh/Documents/us_website/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 134, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/oleh/Documents/us_website/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 487, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/home/oleh/Documents/us_website/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/home/oleh/Documents/us_website/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/oleh/Documents/us_website/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/oleh/Documents/us_website/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 480, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/oleh/Documents/us_website/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/oleh/Documents/us_website/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 696, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/oleh/Documents/us_website/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/oleh/Documents/us_website/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 689, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/oleh/Documents/us_website/us_website/app/urls.py", line 5, in <module>
    from wagtail.admin import urls as wagtailadmin_urls
  File "/home/oleh/Documents/us_website/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/admin/urls/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from wagtail.admin.api import urls as api_urls
  File "/home/oleh/Documents/us_website/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/admin/api/urls.py", line 12, in <module>
    for fn in hooks.get_hooks('construct_admin_api'):
  File "/home/oleh/Documents/us_website/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/core/hooks.py", line 111, in get_hooks
    search_for_hooks()
  File "/home/oleh/Documents/us_website/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/core/hooks.py", line 105, in search_for_hooks
    list(get_app_submodules('wagtail_hooks'))
  File "/home/oleh/Documents/us_website/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/utils/apps.py", line 23, in get_app_submodules
    yield name, import_module('%s.%s' % (name, submodule_name))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home/oleh/Documents/us_website/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/contrib/redirects/wagtail_hooks.py", line 7, in <module>
    from wagtail.contrib.redirects import urls
  File "/home/oleh/Documents/us_website/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/contrib/redirects/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from wagtail.contrib.redirects import views
  File "/home/oleh/Documents/us_website/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/contrib/redirects/views.py", line 23, in <module>
    from wagtail.contrib.redirects.forms import ConfirmImportForm, ImportForm, RedirectForm
  File "/home/oleh/Documents/us_website/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/contrib/redirects/forms.py", line 11, in <module>
    class RedirectForm(forms.ModelForm):
  File "/home/oleh/Documents/us_website/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 306, in __new__
    fields = fields_for_model(
  File "/home/oleh/Documents/us_website/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 224, in fields_for_model
    formfield = f.formfield(**kwargs)
  File "/home/oleh/Documents/us_website/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1139, in formfield
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot create form field for 'site' yet, because its related model 'wagtailcore.Site' has not been loaded yet
```

Here is my installed apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "search",
    "core",
    "pages",
    "wagtail.contrib.forms",
    "wagtail.contrib.redirects",
    "wagtail.embeds",
    "wagtail.sites",
    "wagtail.users",
    "wagtail.snippets",
    "wagtail.documents",
    "wagtail.images",
    "wagtail.search",
    "wagtail.admin",
    "wagtail",
    "modelcluster",
    "taggit",
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "meta",
    "wagtailmetadata",
]
```

And here my pytho and django versions

```
(venv) oleh@OLEH:~/Documents/us_website/us_website$ python
Python 3.10.6 (main, Mar 10 2023, 10:55:28) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django, wagtail
>>> django.VERSION
(4, 0, 10, 'final', 0)
>>> wagtail.VERSION
(2, 16, 3, 'final', 1)
>>>
```

Here are my modules

```
(venv) oleh@OLEH:~/Documents/us_website/us_website$ pip freeze
anyascii==0.3.2
asgiref==3.6.0
beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
certifi==2023.5.7
charset-normalizer==3.1.0
defusedxml==0.7.1
Django==4.0.10
django-filter==21.1
django-meta==2.2.0
django-modelcluster==5.3
django-permissionedforms==0.1
django-taggit==2.1.0
django-treebeard==4.7
djangorestframework==3.14.0
draftjs-exporter==2.1.7
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
filetype==1.2.0
html5lib==1.1
idna==3.4
l18n==2021.3
openpyxl==3.1.2
Pillow==9.5.0
psycopg2==2.9.6
python-dotenv==1.0.0
pytz==2023.3
requests==2.30.0
six==1.16.0
soupsieve==2.4.1
sqlparse==0.4.4
tablib==3.4.0
telepath==0.3
urllib3==2.0.2
wagtail==2.16.3
wagtail-metadata-mixin==2.0.2
webencodings==0.5.1
Willow==1.4.1
xlrd==2.0.1
XlsxWriter==3.1.1
xlwt==1.3.0
```

I cant find the reason of the error. I've check my settings with wagtail demo site's settings.

Looks like the problem is in "File "/home/oleh/Documents/us_website/us_website/app/urls.py", line 5, in 
from wagtail.admin import urls as wagtailadmin_urls", but I cant uderstand what is wrong.

How can i fix this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please show what you have for INSTALLED_APPS in your settings file? It should include "wagtail.sites". And which versions of Django and Wagtail are you using?

Comment: I've added information about my project

Comment: I found the reason. The problem appears after installing wagtail-metadata-mixin package. During its installation wagtail and django versions were downgraded.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is jumping out at me. It is almost certainly some flavor of circular import or not deferring instantiating a class. At a guess you were previously able to run `makemigrations` so I would probably use `git bisect` to figure out what commit broke things and then look for some place you could reorder importing things or perhaps replace `from foo.models import Bar` with `apps.get_model('foo', 'bar')`.